# Unable to install python3-libnvinfer package, unmet dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, tensorrt, tensorrt-python

I'm trying to install `python3-libnvinfer-dev` for TensorRT (Tensorflow). I have Ubuntu 22.04 with python `3.10.4` but I use Anaconda's python `3.9.7`. I have Nvidia 510 drivers, CUDA 11.6 and Cudnn 8. The issue is, when I run `sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev` it shows this error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: python3-libnvinfer : Depends: python3 (< 3.9) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: try this maybe solve your problem `sudo apt-get autoremove`  , and run your command

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause:** The error message says that the package requires you to have python `< 3.9` but you told you have Python `3.9.7` in your Anaconda.

#### Solution 1

Downgrade your Python to 3.8 in your Anaconda.

#### Solution 2

If you want to try to fix the conflict in apt you should run this command

```
sudo aptitude install python3-libnvinfer-dev
```

Then follow the instructions in the prompts. The tool tries to offer you different alternatives how to resolve the conflicts between the packages.

#### Solution 3

This is not probably what you want but if you install the package on your system without Anaconda it should work as you are using Python 3.10

As a curiosity, I was able to install the latest `python3-libnvinfer-dev` for TensorRT 8.4.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8.10 and CUDA 11.6.